# fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, cmake, zbar

I downloaded the [zbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/?source=typ_redirect) library and cloned the [opencv-zbar](https://github.com/rportugal/opencv-zbar) repo in my home directory. Then I ran the following command `$cmake .` which gave my the error

> ```
> -- Could NOT find ZBAR (missing:  ZBAR_LIBRARIES ZBAR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
> Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
> ZBAR_LIBRARIES
>     linked by target "zbar_opencv" in directory /home/surabhi/opencv-zbar
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/home/surabhi/opencv-zbar/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> ```

I then made two changes in my CMakeCache.txt as follows

```
//Path to a file.
ZBAR_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/zbar

//Path to a library.
ZBAR_LIBRARIES:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libzbar.so
```

because the were set to `NOTFOUND`.

It then gave me no errors

> ```
> -- Found ZBAR: /usr/lib/libzbar.so  
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/surabhi/opencv-zbar
> ```

But when I run `make`

It gives the error:

> ```
> fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
>  #include <zbar.h>
>                   ^
> compilation terminated.
> ```

I don't understand why I get this error as It says **Found ZBAR** when I run `cmake`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to do actually use the include dirs somewhere in your *CMakeLists.txt* so CMake knows that you actually want to use these include paths.

Examples:

`include_directories(${ZBAR_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Or the more modern, recommended way:

`target_include_directories(zbar_opencv PRIVATE ${ZBAR_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Comment: I added the above mentioned target in my CMakeLists, but still get the error zbar.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Okay. Check with `make VERBOSE=1` how your compiler is invoked (check if the `-I` flags passed to it are as expected).

Comment: I managed to solve the error. The thing is that I had just downloaded zbar and extracted its contents in my home directory and not installed it. After installing zbar, it all works fine. Thanks for the help.